# Android. Activity not start from service

Tags: android, android-activity, service, device-admin

I tried to start activity for enabling device administration mode but admin activity did not start. 
It`s my service class

```
class MainService : Service() {

private val description = "Some Description About Your Admin"

private var mComponentName: ComponentName? = null

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {.
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    mComponentName = ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver::class.java)
    val i = Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN)
    i.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    i.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mComponentName)
    i.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, description)
    startActivity(i)
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
}
}
```

**UPDATE**
1) I want initialization administration mode from my service.
2) Debug execute all code lines.
3) My file AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".AdminReceiver"
              android:label="@string/sample_device_admin"
              android:description="@string/sample_device_admin_description"
              android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                   android:resource="@xml/device_admin_sample"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".MainService" android:exported="true"/>
    <service
            android:name="FirebaseService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: Q: What exactly happens when you start your application from Android Studio, in debug mode?  Q: What did you *expect* to happen?  Q: Please update your post with your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: I update my post

Comment: What android version?

Comment: Version android 9

Comment: I added "Kotlin" to your tags - the code doesn't appear to be Java ;)  FYI, if this *were* Java, then you *must* call `super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)` as the *FIRST LINE* of your method...  PS: I don't see anything "obviously" wrong with your AndroidManifest.xml.  Thanx for posting it.